# No leaves on tree tops. What’s wrong?

Tags: trees, diseases, tree-care

[image: Twisted Baby Locust]
[image: Scarlet Oak]

I’ve got two trees that didn’t get leaves on their tops. Should I be concerned? One is a twisted baby locust and the other is a scarlet oak tree. It did get really warm here and then freeze in the spring. The trees have had plenty of rainfall.

Additional photos
[image: oak pic 2]
[image: twisted baby locust 2]

Comment: How well are the plant nearby? Could you make a close-up photo of one branch without leave? (the buds). For me: destroyed buds because: late freeze or caterpillars.

Comment: Twisted locust is delicate. You have to keep it watered. Round here, US, even the 80 year old red oaks are looking scruffy like yours. Winters have been wrong, and they are dying. Your apical meristem (top, or leader)is dead. I'd get a different tree. My swamp oak (lobate, not pin leaves) is doing fine. Maybe one of those?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I’ll take more photos tonight when I’m back home.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Watering definitely is not the problem. We’ve had flooding in our area due to the amount of rain we’ve had. I wasn’t sure if our freeze this spring after we already had really warm temps had something to do with it.

Comment: @thecoolmacdude OK. This is winter damage though? The local Parks and rec. are always trying to grow twisty locusts and maples and such, and they usually have bad luck with them. These people know what they're doing, but the plants are twitchy. Pin oak climate climate seems to be moving north. Couple times a week I wake to the sound of chain saws cutting down another big one. Our city center will soon look like new suburbs. Linden have been hit too. We're currently 1/2 to 1 zone higher than we where 20 years ago. That affects what trees will do well.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Added photos above

Comment: To me, it seems winter damages. Maybe @WayfaringStranger can answer better with the new photos.

Comment: I had similar issues with a Catalpa (three-year old tree from seed) and a simlilarly aged redbud. If I had to bet money, I'd say your winter saw at least one night colder than 25 below zero Fahrenheit. The last photo is a perfect twin to the way the top of my catalpa looks. I don't know if it was the bitter cold (Catalpas should NOT have been affected by -29F) or a sudden temperature swing that caused the die back. Few redbuds here even bloomed this spring and all catalpas in my area leafed out only in early June - a good 4 weeks later than normal (I thought mine had died).